Are LLVM initialization functions thread-safe?
Are functions such as LLVMInitializeX86Target safe to be called from within a thread function while also being called from within another thread function, or are they only allowed to be called from one parent thread (e.g. the main thread)?
I have searched for the documentation of LLVM, but nothing seems to be clear with that regard. I have also looked inside the implementation of the example function above, and inside it uses a static PassRegistry instance. PassRegistry is documented to be not thread-safe, but the implementation of each method inside that class uses a RW  mutex lock. In addition, that note was added as part of a commit code that was removed since then but not sure if the not thread-safe note still applies.

Probably because you should be asking the LLVM people. Also likely because it seems odd to be initializing a target in multiple threads, instead of once before starting additional threads.

Not really odd. It's a common practice to have something like std::call_once (or equivalent) to safely lazy initialize a static object on the first thread that demands it. It doesn't need to be initialized in main. Destructing the static object, however, must be done in the main thread only. llvm_shutdown notes that too, and logic-wise it makes sense. As a matter of fact, Inkwell, a safe LLVM wrapper for Rust, does something like what I mentioned above (lock guard on all initialization functions).
